# Trying to get game to level up and use new enemy

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a new enemy every time the hero levels up. The code itself works without a problem. The player levels, up, he uses magic and mana, the enemy hits back, and all that jazz. I just can't figure out a way to throw in a new enemy every time the player kills the enemy. Any ideas?

```
class Character:
     def __init__(self, name, health, level):
          self.name = name
          self.health = health
          self.level = level
          self.levelup_counter = level + 1

     def attack(self):
          c2.health -= 2

c1 = Character("Hero", 10, 1)
c2 = Character("Monster 1", 10, 2)
c3 = Character("Monster 2", 20, 3)
c4 = Character("Monster 3", 40, 4)
# monster_list = [c2,c3,c4]

def stats():
    print("_______________________________________")
    print("Your stats \t\tEnemy Stats")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(f"Health: {c1.health}\t\tHealth: {c2.health}")
    print(f"Level: {c1.level}\t\tLevel: {c2.level}")

while True:
     attack = input("Enter 1 to attack: ")
     c1.attack()
     stats()
     if c2.health == 0:
          c1.level += 1
          print("YOu killed the monster!\nYou leveled up!")
          continue
```

UPDATE:

UPDATE:

I made a few changes and added a for loop to iterate over the monster list. Now I have two problems. First, the monsters keep iterating (obviously) instead of simply one monster fighting until death. Then, a new monster will appear. Second, I can't remove a monster from the list after death. I get the error "TypeError: 'Character' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

```
class Character:
     def __init__(self, name, health, level):
          self.name = name
          self.health = health
          self.level = level
          self.levelup_counter = level + 1
     def attack(self):
          m.health -= 2
     def monster_death(self):
          if m.health == 0:
               monster_list.pop(m)


c1 = Character("Hero", 10, 1)
c2 = Character("Monster 1", 10, 2)
c3 = Character("Monster 2", 20, 3)
c4 = Character("Monster 3", 40, 4)

monster_list = [c2,c3,c4]

def stats():
    print("_______________________________________")
    print("Your stats \t\tEnemy Stats")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(f"Health: {c1.health}\t\tHealth: {m.health}")
    print(f"Level: {c1.level}\t\tLevel: {m.level}")

i=0
while True:
     i+=1
     for m in monster_list:
          attack = input("Enter 1 to attack: ")
          c1.attack()
          stats()
          if m.health == 0:
               c1.level += 1
               print("YOu killed the monster!\nYou leveled up!")
               m.monster_death()
               continue
```

Comment: keep elements on list and use `for`-loop to work with them - and then you can append new enemy to list or remove it when it died. And with list you may have more enemies on every level.

Comment: @furas Yeah, that didnt quite work. I update the code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: if you want to `one monster fighting until death` then always use `monster_list[0]` instead of `for`-loop. And when it is death then also remove `monster_list[0]`. And new mosters append at the end of list.

Comment: @furas There isn;t really. It just says TypeError: 'Character' object cannot be interpreted as an integer", and that the problem is in line 50, which is realated to the monster_list.pop(m) method.

Comment: first: inside class you should use `self.` instead `m.`

Comment: it is only end of FULL error message - full error starts with word `Traceback` - and you should put FULL error message. It will be more useful then infomation that problem is in line 50. Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers.

Comment: `pop()` needs index on list, but `m` is object `Character` - you should rather use `remove()` - `monster_list.remove(m)` or rather with `self` - `monster_list.remove(self)`

Comment: @furas Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/test/tiny.py", line 77, in <module>
    m.monster_death()
  File "c:/Users/Desktop/test/tiny.py", line 50, in monster_death
    monster_list.pop(m)
TypeError: 'Character' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @furas the remove option worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep monsters on list and fight always with first monster on list - `monster_list[0]`. And when you kill it then `remove()` it - and then you can append new monster at the end of list.

---

Minimal working code

```
# --- classes ---

class Character:
    
     def __init__(self, name, health, level):
          self.name = name
          self.health = health
          self.level = level
          self.levelup_counter = level + 1
          
     def attack(self):
          self.health -= 2
          
     def monster_death(self):
          if self.health <= 0:  # better check `<=` instead of `==`
               monsters.remove(self)

     def __str__(self):
        return f'name: {self.name}, health: {self.health}, level: {self.level}'
    
# --- functions ---

def stats(player, monster):
    print("_______________________________________")
    print("Your stats \t\tEnemy Stats")
    print("---------------------------------------")
    print(f"Health: {player.health}\t\tHealth: {monster.health}")
    print(f"Level: {player.level}\t\tLevel: {monster.level}")

# --- main ---

player = Character("Hero", 10, 1)

monsters = [
    Character("Monster 1", 10, 2),
    Character("Monster 2", 20, 3),
    Character("Monster 3", 40, 4),
]    

#monsters = []
#for i in range(1, 4):
#    monsters.append( Character(f"Monster {i}", i*10, i+1),

i = 3  # used for monster's name

while monsters:
    m = monsters[0]
    print('New monster attacked:', m)  # it will use `__str__` to display `m`
    while True: 
        attack = input("Enter 1 to attack: ")
        m.attack()
        stats(player, m)
        if m.health <= 0:  # better check `<=` instead of `==`
             player.level += 1
             print("You killed the monster!\nYou leveled up!")
             m.monster_death()
             i += 1
             monsters.append( Character(f"Monster {i}", i*10, i+1) )
             break  # exit nearest `while`
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix the first issue, just add a while loop for each monster that continues until the health is less than or equal to 0. I have shown this in the code below. Also your "i" counter was completely unused from what I could tell.

```
while True:
     for m in monster_list:
          while m.health > 0:
               attack = input("Enter 1 to attack: ")
               c1.attack()
               stats()
               if m.health <= 0:
                    c1.level += 1
                    print("YOu killed the monster!\nYou leveled up!")
                    m.monster_death()
```

As for the second issue with removing the monsters from the list, I think that is a bad idea while you are iterating through a for loop. By removing the monsters from the list while looping through them, you are going to get indexing errors and it will skip monster number 3. If you want to get rid of the error you are getting though, simply change this line: `monster_list.pop(m)` to `monster_list.remove(m)`.

What @furas said above is a good suggestion. You could do something like this (pseudocode but you get the idea):

```
while len(monster_list) > 0:
     while monster_list[0].health > 0:
          # attack
          if monster_list[0].health <= 0:
               # kill monster and remove monster_list[0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah the i counter was there because I was trying stuff. But dang, all I was mssing was the extra while loop. I would upvote your answer if I could, but i dont have enough stack cred...

Comment: No worries! Glad it was helpful!

Comment: @PythonFiend Now you have enough Stack reputation to UpVote, you can upvote this answer now.